# What is the correct tense in this context?

Tags: tense

Consider these expressions:

> This is one of those days when nothing (I am doing) **is working out** for me.
>
> This is one of those days when nothing (I do) **works out** for me.

Which tense should I use in this context? Or are both of them correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are grammatical, and both mean much the same thing. However, the first places the emphasis on *this . . . day*, whereas the second places the emphasis on *those days*.

Answer (score 2):

> This is one of those day when nothing (I am doing) is working out for me.

This would indicate that the *day* is still in progress. It is possible something may work out during that day.

Regarding the second phrase, it needs some correction/clarification first. I am guessing its:

> This *is* one of those days when nothing (I do) works out for me.

In this case there will be no more related activity, or no expectation of anything going right on that day. 
In this case, it may be clearer to use the past tense

> This **was** one of those days when nothing (I **did**) **worked** out for me.